# Function Prototyping Issues

Tags: c

Thanks everyone for the advice!  I no longer have the function inside a switch statement, but now it's giving me fatal errors.  Does anybody know why it won't compile now?  Am I still prototyping or defining it wrong?  Again thanks in advance!

```
uhunix:/home04/y/yingkit/ee150% gcc functions2.c 
Undefined                       first referenced
symbol                             in file
largest_of_three                    /var/tmp//ccEk23i2.o
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to a.out
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is the entire code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
//include macro functions if any


int main(void)
{
   int repeat = 1;
   int option = 0;   

   while(repeat == 1)
   {   
      printf("\nOPTIONS:\n\n");
      printf("1. Find the largest of three numbers.\n");
      printf("2. Calculate the factorial of a number.\n");
      printf("3. Truncate a number.\n");
      printf("4. Round a number.\n");
      printf("5. Find the inverse of a number.\n");
      printf("0. Exit the program.\n\n");
      printf("What do you want to do\?\n");

      scanf("%i", &option);

      float largest_of_three(float, float, float); //prototype

      if(option == 0)
      {    
         break;
      }

      if(option == 1)
      {

            float x = 0;
            float y = 0;
            float z = 0;
            float result = 0;

            printf("First number: ");
            scanf("%f", &x);
            printf("Second number: ");
            scanf("%f", &y);
            printf("Third number: ");
            scanf("%f", &z);   

            result = largest_of_three(x, y, z); //calling

            float largest_of_three(float x, float y, float z)
            {
               float w = 0;
               if(x > y && x > z)
               {
                  w = x;
               }
               else
               {
                  if(y > x && y > z)
                  {
                     w = y;
                  }   
                  else //middle
                  {
                     if(z > x && z > y)
                     {
                        w = z;
                     }
                     else  
                     {
                        printf("There is no single greatest number.\n");
                     }
                  } //end middle else
               } //end outer else
               printf("The greatest number is %f.", w);
               return w;
            } //end largest_of_three function
      } //end option 1
      getchar( ); //to prevent buffer issues
      printf("Would you like to do another operation\? Type y for yes, n for no.\n");

      char yesno = 'y';
      scanf("%c", &yesno);
      if(yesno == 'y' || yesno == 'Y')
      {
         repeat = 1;
      }
      else
      {
         repeat = 0;
      }


   } //end while loop 

   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a prototype there? Where is this funcion defined? What does the error message tell you?

Comment: It would be better to move the declaration and definition outside the `switch`.

Comment: It would help if you provided the full file so that we can see what the line numbers in the warnings correspond to in the code.

Comment: "I've put a function in a switch case statement" - well, don't. That's just not allowed in C.

Comment: Ahh ok, didn't know that.  Thanks!

Comment: The updated code still has the same problem. The function is not allowed to be inside another function.

Comment: Ahh it has to be outside the MAIN function.  Removing it from the switch did nothing.  Both the declaration and the definition had to be outside the main function.  Fixed it and the program runs smooth.  Thanks for all the help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

The code on line 57 is illegal.  Functions may not be defined inside other functions in ISO C.

The error suggests your compiler has an extension to allow nested functions, giving them *internal linkage*. But you gave a prototype with external linkage, a mismatch.

To fix this, stop using nested functions. (You probably could fix it by adding `static` to the start of the prototype, however this is bad coding style).

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll just get rid of the switch statement then.